# select with ng-init and filter on ng-option still shows empty line

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-init

I am new to angularJS and I am struggling with a select issue. On my other selects I have managed to display what I wanted without any issue. But on this one I have a filter to flatten the array used for the list, since the elements I need are nested deeply in the array.

Here is the fiddle :[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vonwolf/5LTjD/3/)

`<select ng-model='selectedFunctionField' ng-init="selectedFunctionField = fields[0]" ng-options="field as field.display for field in fields|flatten" class="form-control"></select>`

My issue is the empty line that I can't get rid off. I tried everything I found on SO : ng-init with a string, ng-init with an object, ng-init with a function, with a $scope variable, etc somehow something is wrong in my code but I can't see what...

Thanks for your help on this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nginit should be,

```
ng-init="selectedFunctionField = fields[0].columns[0]"
```

As you are filtering the data and returning columns.

Sample Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/FF0hupHo0Qc2i2Ee5QVP?p=preview

Comment: Many thanks for this! Unfornately I over-simplified my case in the fiddle and I left out the filter parameter thing. Your solution works great with one element in the array but it still leaves an empty line with 2. I updated your plunkr to illustrate this : [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/L7tgOoKdjXWQUFLNaKCt?p=preview)

Comment: Ok you are filtering your data by your custom filter now. The value fields[0].columns[0]is not getting displayed because its not in the filtered results, so its selecting a empty option. To workaround this problem, you can use a $filter service in controller and initialize it using a function.
Updated Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/1WVZAPpSiWmP5E9eMu2i?p=preview